# R select rows in matrix from another vector (match, %in)

Tags: r, select, match

Say I have a dataframe with 6 columns and 100000 rows. I want to select rows in matrix `originScen` based on the indices/numbers in another vector `reducedScenIds` (10,000 rows). I select the rows by checking if the value of each member of Y matches the value in column 1 of the dataframe X. Now the first column can have multiple matches for each value of Y.

So I used the below

```
reducedSet <- originScen[which(originScen[,1] %in% reducedScenarioIds),]
```

I am ok with the results except that `which` and `%in%` seems to destroy the order of `reducedScenarioIds` vector. The final `reducedSet` has rows selected based on ascending order of ids found in the `reducedScenarioIds` vector and not the exact same order.

The `originScen[,1]` can have duplicate entries for each entry in `reducedScenarioIds`

Anyone have an alternate solution?

Thanks

Comment: You should be able to drop the `which` and just use `%in%`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
reducedSet <- originScen[originScen[,1] %in% reducedScenarioIds,][order(na.exclude(match(originScen[,1], reducedScenarioIds))),]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Works perfect. Don't understand how though. So first the reduced set of scenarios are produced with  originScen[originScen[,1] %in% reducedScenarioIds,] then the second part would order it in the way the indices appear in  reducedScenarioIds. How does the na.exclude figure here?

Comment: I've added `na.exclude` to remove the cases where `originScen[,1]` contains values not present in `reducedScenarioIds`, as the result of `match` in these cases is `NA`.