# How to feed in the arguments of a function used in rollapplyr FUN

Tags: r, rollapply

Let's say I have the following data:

```
input <- data.frame(id=rep(c('A', 'B'), c(10, 10)),year=rep(1:10, 2),
                  y=c(rnorm(10), rnorm(10)),x1 = c(rnorm(10),rnorm(10)))
```

I want to use rollapplyr to do a rolling regression. First I define a beta function :

```
# Simple Regression
beta <- function(x, indepvar, depvar) {
  a <- coef(lm(formula = indepvar ~ depvar, data = x))
  return(a)
}
```

Now I want to use this function in a rollapplyr setting. (I know that I can define the function within the rollapplyr, but I want to understand the concept.)

```
rollapplyr(input, width = 6,
              FUN = beta, x = input, indepvar = y, depvar = x1,
              by.column = FALSE)
```

I am trying to feed the arguments of beta function by defining input, indepvar and depvar in the code above. But I am getting this error:

> Error in FUN(data[posns, ], ...) : unused argument (data[posns, ])

There is a question here: [unused arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18220497/unused-arguments-error-using-apply-in-r) but I don't understand what argument I am not using. what does this error mean in my context? Why am I getting it?

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do with `rollapplyr` and what package it comes from? I have never seen this function before.

Comment: @useR The rollapply function comes from zoo package. What I am trying to do is to run my regression on a rolling basis in windows with width = 6 here (just for example).

Comment: And what is the desired result?

Comment: @useR Let me explain on the input data above. You can see that I have y and x1 for 10 years, for two differents ids (A and B). I want to run rolling window regressions and save the beta s. For example, the first regerssion is from year = 1 to year = 7. Then the next regression is from year = 2 to year = 8. After that from year = 3 to year = 9. You can see.
(my next step is to do it by groups, but I want to go step by step here, and I am stuck in the first step btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are a few issues here. Let me walk you through the most critical ones:

```
# Simple Regression
beta <- function(x, indepvar, depvar) {
  a <- coef(lm(formula = indepvar ~ depvar, data = x))
  return(a)
}
```

The way you have written your function `beta` means that you have to input the data `x`, the `indepvar` column and the `depvar` column. But this would not work for `lm` because what `indepvar` and `depvar` *contains* are fed in, instead of the *variable names*. For instance, the following would not work:

```
beta(input, y, x1)
```

> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'y' not found

This is because `y` and `x1` do not exist outside of `input`. Your `rollapplyr` has the same issue. One way to get around this is to write:

```
beta <- function(indepvar, depvar) {
  a <- coef(lm(indepvar ~ depvar))
  return(a)
}
```

And explicitly input the columns like:

```
# > beta(input[,3],input[,4])
# (Intercept)      depvar 
#   0.1308993   0.2373399
```

Now this works:

```
rollapplyr(input[3:4], width = 6,
           FUN = function(x) beta(x[,1], x[,2]),
           by.column = FALSE)

#      (Intercept)        depvar
# [1,] -0.04987909  0.6433585022
# [2,] -0.23739671  0.7527017129
# [3,] -0.40483456  0.5833452315
# [4,] -0.28191172  0.6660916836
# [5,]  0.02886934  0.5334114615
# [6,]  0.17284232  0.8126499211
# [7,]  0.01236415  0.3194661428
# [8,]  0.48156300 -0.1532216150
# [9,]  0.75965765 -0.1993015431
# [10,]  0.80509109 -0.1822009137
# [11,]  0.55055694 -0.0005880675
# [12,]  0.53963291 -0.0262970723
# [13,]  0.46509011  0.0570725348
# [14,]  0.33227459  0.1598345855
# [15,] -0.20316429  0.2757045612
```

If you want to be able to call the columns by name, you can write your `beta` function as:

```
library(zoo)
beta <- function(x, indepvar, depvar) {
  a <- coef(lm(as.formula(paste(indepvar, "~", depvar)), 
               data = x))
  return(a)
}

rollapplyr(input[3:4], width = 6,
           FUN = function(x) beta(as.data.frame(x), "y", "x1"),
           by.column = FALSE)

#      (Intercept)            x1
# [1,] -0.04987909  0.6433585022
# [2,] -0.23739671  0.7527017129
# [3,] -0.40483456  0.5833452315
# [4,] -0.28191172  0.6660916836
# [5,]  0.02886934  0.5334114615
# [6,]  0.17284232  0.8126499211
# [7,]  0.01236415  0.3194661428
# [8,]  0.48156300 -0.1532216150
# [9,]  0.75965765 -0.1993015431
# [10,]  0.80509109 -0.1822009137
# [11,]  0.55055694 -0.0005880675
# [12,]  0.53963291 -0.0262970723
# [13,]  0.46509011  0.0570725348
# [14,]  0.33227459  0.1598345855
# [15,] -0.20316429  0.2757045612
```

Notice I have to supply `input[3:4]` instead of just `input` to `rollapplyr` because apparently `rollapplyr` only takes matrix as input. If `input` has mixed types, `rollapplyr` coerce it to a matrix of characters, which is not desirable. So I have to both supply the numeric only columns *and* coerce it back to data.frame with `as.data.frame` for `lm` to work.

Here are two link that discuss this issue with `rollapplyr`:

[Is there a function like rollapply for data.frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13771385/is-there-a-function-like-rollapply-for-data-frame)

[Can `ddply` (or similar) do a sliding window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7225992/can-ddply-or-similar-do-a-sliding-window)

Comment: Thanks a lot, @useR. The new code worked for me. I think I should spend more time to get more comfprtable with R.